# Android get textview width and height before the setting text and rendering

Tags: android, textview, width

I am trying to get the width of a textview setting the text. Here's the Code I am using:

```
public int getTextViewEffectedWidth(TextView textView, String content){
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            Paint paint = textView.getPaint();
            paint.getTextBounds(content, 0, content.length(), bounds);
            return bounds.width();
}
```

But this method returns larger width. Example:

1. I need set in textview value "6978"
2. This method was calculate width = 46 (By the way returned value in dp or sp ? I set in dp, cause in px this value in not enough.)
3. If I set textview's width 46 dp or sp, TextView will has extra place
   [image: extra place. to large width]

I need to get the width value which would be consistent with width="wrap_content"
[image: normal]

TextView size and font have default values.

Answer (score 0):

try this,you will get the value in pixel;

```
 int width=convertToPixel(textView.getWidth());
 int height=convertToPixel(textView.getHeight());


private int convertToPixel(int n) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, n, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        return (int) px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little while after your request, but are you running the check in an OnGlobalLayoutListener?

If not, then the view won't be completely drawn on the screen, and you won't have the dimensions available.

Inside the onGlobalLayout() you can called measuredWidth and measuredHeight.

I hope this helps, if not you, then someone else.